# Piping in awk script not working correctly

Tags: json, awk

I have a newline seperated, json'd output of an observation programing that runs in cron.
Every 5 minutes it appends a new observation to a file.

In order to look for something (anything) being down, and then get the date of the json object on the line, I'm running this:

```
 awk '/down/ {print $0 | json date }' observations
```

Here, json is a script I found somewhere - json K outputs the value that corresponds to the key K in the json object I.

Anyway, running the one-liner above causes awk to not print anything, and the exit code is 141.

This is mawk 1.2, on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

awk is not shell. You can't directly call an external command from awk any more than you could from a C program. man awk for how to call external commands.

Comment: Anyone care to share why the downvote? The answer is 100% correct.

Comment: This is plain wrong. See, for example, http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_38.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337232/the-usage-of-pipe-in-awk, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43147/piping-in-awk-scripts.

Comment: No, this answer is 100% correct. You said "I want to know why my awk script doesn't work, rather than how to solve the problem." and my answer tells you EXACTLY why. See the references you posted and the awk man page.

Comment: I didn't just say 'read the man page' I told you what to look for in the man page - how to call external commands. I told you why your script didn't work and I told you exactly what to look up in the man page to tell you how to do what.

Comment: The word external isn't even in the man page for awk. There are no mentions in the awk man page for pipe. The links provided above demonstrate use of a pipe, for piping some chunk of data in awk out to an external command, without using system. It seems there are double quotes missing in my original question, but putting them in does not solve the problem.

Comment: The only function that supports piping in original `awk` and `mawk` is `getline`. Here is a [comparison](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/awk-nawk-gawk/) of awk variants.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your observations file looks (maybe post it?), but don't you want something like this:

```
grep down observations | json date
```

Ok, you could also try:

```
awk '/down/{c="echo " $1 "| json date";system(c)}' observations
```

Comment: No, because each line is a json object. I'd have to do `for i in grep down observations; do echo $i | json date; done` which almost works, but I want to know why my awk script doesn't work, rather than how to solve the problem.

Comment: Did my second suggestion do the trick for you? If so, please accept it as the answer. If not, please let us know what happened so we can assist you further.

Comment: No. You want to change $1 to $0 so it's the whole line. Also, echo disgregards double-quotes, which surround strings in json, so it's no longer proper json. Hence, json fails on `echo $0 ...`

Comment: Ok, replace the "echo" with a write to a temp file of $0, and "cat" the temp file into your json tool.

Comment: Or put single quotes around your string before passing it to echo so that it doesn't drop double quotes. echo single quote"hi"single quote  produces "hi".